# PHP Group array by date

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following array that gathers data from purchases, visits and coupons generated in my application:

```
    array:10 [
      0 => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-18"
        "cupoms" => 9
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-19"
        "cupoms" => 1
      ]
      2 => {#1421 
        +"dt": "2020-11-14"
        +"visits": 1
      }
      3 => {#1423 
        +"dt": "2020-11-15"
        +"visits": 1
      }
      4 => {#860 
        +"dt": "2020-11-16"
        +"visits": 9
      }
      5 => {#530 
        +"dt": "2020-11-18"
        +"visits": 48
      }
      6 => {#1527 
        +"dt": "2020-11-19"
        +"visits": 3
      }
      7 => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-15"
        "orders" => 1
      ]
      8 => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-17"
        "orders" => 3
      ]
      9 => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-19"
        "orders" => 4
      ]
    ]
```

I need to group it by date (more specifically the 'dt' field), so that the data is like as follows:

```
    "dt" => "2020-11-18"
    "cupoms" => 9
    "visits"=> 48
    
    "dt" => "2020-11-19"
    "cupoms" => 1
    "visits" => 3
    "orders" => 4
    
    "dt" => "2020-11-14"
    "visits"=> 1
```

I tried a few loops, but to no avail

Comment: where are these loops that you're referring, you forgot to add it in your question

Comment: It seems some of your array elements are arrays, and others are objects. Is this correct?

Comment: If you are using laravel, the best and easiest way to do it, is using collections, see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby

Comment: @nick Yes, i converted objects to array and used Manuvo solution. Thank you

Comment: @r1tt3r Please take a look again at my answer as I found an oversight on my part, I already updated it. You're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
    *I edited the answer because I realized that it wasn't adding the numerical values together, it was just taking the first value; The code got a bit more complicated but there is no straightforward way to do it with collections, I'd sill recommend using collections instead of loops of arrays*

---

With laravel you can take advantage of collections, they are very powerfull, here is a working example:

```
        $array = [
      [
        "dt" => "2020-11-18",
        "cupoms" => 9
      ],
      [
        "dt" => "2020-11-19",
        "cupoms" => 1
      ],
      [
        "dt"=> "2020-11-14",
        "visits"=> 1
      ],
      [
        "dt"=> "2020-11-15",
        "visits"=> 1
      ],
      [
        "dt"=> "2020-11-16",
        "visits"=> 9
      ],
      [
        "dt"=> "2020-11-18",
        "visits"=> 48
      ],
      [
        "dt"=> "2020-11-19",
        "visits"=> 3
      ],
      [
        "dt" => "2020-11-15",
        "orders" => 1
      ],
      [
        "dt" => "2020-11-17",
        "orders" => 3
      ],
      [
        "dt" => "2020-11-19",
        "orders" => 4
      ]
    ];

    $collection = collect($array);

    $grouped = $collection->groupBy('dt');

    //up to this step($merged_rec) you already preserved and grouped all the values 
    //and you can sum the values manually if you wish, 
    //but in the next step I will suggest a solution using collections
    $merged_rec = $grouped->map(function ($items) {
        return collect($items)->reduce(function ($carry, $item) {
            return collect($carry)->mergeRecursive($item);
        }, collect([]));
    });
    
    //this will reduce the numeric arrays to a single value (sum) 
    //using collections
    $summed = $merged_rec->map(function ($items){
        return collect($items->map(function($subitems) {
            if( is_array($subitems) && count($subitems) > 0 && is_numeric($subitems[0]) ){
                return collect($subitems)->sum();
            } else {
                return $subitems;
            }
        }));
    });

    print_r($summed->toArray());
```

this will output:

```
    array:6 [
      "2020-11-18" => array:3 [
        "dt" => array:2 [
          0 => "2020-11-18"
          1 => "2020-11-18"
        ]
        "cupoms" => 9
        "visits" => 48
      ]
      "2020-11-19" => array:3 [
        "dt" => array:3 [
          0 => "2020-11-19"
          1 => "2020-11-19"
          2 => "2020-11-19"
        ]
        "cupoms" => 1
        "visits" => 3
      ]
      "2020-11-14" => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-14"
        "visits" => 1
      ]
      "2020-11-15" => array:3 [
        "dt" => array:2 [
          0 => "2020-11-15"
          1 => "2020-11-15"
        ]
        "visits" => 1
        "orders" => 1
      ]
      "2020-11-16" => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-16"
        "visits" => 9
      ]
      "2020-11-17" => array:2 [
        "dt" => "2020-11-17"
        "orders" => 3
      ]
    ]
```

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby

Answer (score 0):

Just loop and sum the different values:

```
foreach($array as $v) { 
    if(!isset($result[$v['dt']])) {
        $result[$v['dt']] = array('dt' => $v['dt'], 'cupoms' => 0, 'visits' => 0, 'orders' => 0);
    }
    $result[$v['dt']]['cupoms'] += $v['cupoms'];
    $result[$v['dt']]['visits'] += $v['visits'];
    $result[$v['dt']]['orders'] += $v['orders'];
}
```

If you want to eliminate ones that have no `visits` or `orders`, then inside the loop after summing:

```
$result[$v['dt']] = array_filter($result[$v['dt']]);
```

Then if you want integer keys (no reason for it), after the loop:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```